# npm build dockerfile need help for deep dependency tree

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile, npm-install

The first thought is to use `npm install --save-dev xxxxx` inside dockerfile but My app has more than 70 dev dependencies and you can assume an average of 10 peer dependency so manually doing is going to be a pain and infeasible solution. Though I am assuming manual installation of 700+ dependencies will work however I am searching for a smart solution to prepare my docker image.

I am doing this currently for 1 microservice and i would like to replicate/perform something similar other 7 services hence I don't want to perform this manually. 
Help is appreciated.

Comment: All of your dependencies should generally be listed in your `package.json` file, so you can `COPY package.json .` and then `RUN npm install` to get all of them in one shot.  Is this file missing or incomplete?

Comment: Thanks, I got it correct, My package.json was corrupted so it was behaving unexpectedly.